# form.checkValidity checking that two password fields match

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

First post here so please be gentle. I'm trying to self learn how to write a responsive website for a local club. Is there any way of checking that two password fields are identical and error accordingly using the bootstrap 4 method of form validation? I can do it server side but since I am doing a fair amount of client side form validation, it would be nice if I could check that the passwords were the same before submitting the form.

```
<form class="container" id="form-validation" method="post" action="./register.php" novalidate>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 mb-3">
        <label for="validation1">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="validation1" placeholder="Username" required pattern="^[_a-zA-Z0-9\-]{5,15}$">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Must be alpha-numeric, dash or underscore, between 5 & 15 characters
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 mb-3">
        <label for="validation2">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd1" id="validation2" placeholder="Password" required pattern="^[_a-zA-Z0-9\-]{5,15}$">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Must be alpha-numeric, dash or underscore, between 5 & 15 characters
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 mb-3">
        <label for="validation3">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd2" id="validation3" placeholder="Re-enter Password" required pattern="^[_a-zA-Z0-9\-]{5,15}$">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Must be alpha-numeric, dash or underscore, between 5 & 15 characters and match original Password
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 mb-3">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Send" name="registerbtn">Register</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>


(function() {
    "use strict";
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var form = document.getElementById("form-validation");
        form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
            if (form.checkValidity() == false) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
            form.classList.add("was-validated");
        }, false);
    }, false);
}());
```

Comment: show what code you have tried to match the two passwords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this should work.

```
var form = document.getElementById("form-validation");
 form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {          
      if ( document.getElementById("validation2").value != document.getElementById("validation3").value ) {
          alert("Password mismatch");
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
      }
      else if (form.checkValidity() == false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
      }
      form.classList.add("was-validated");
    }, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this validation through the JavaScript constraint validation API, it's a `customError`, which you can set prior to form submission.

I'll provide the example for BootStrap4 and assume jQuery as an optional but common BootStrap dependency to abbreviate `$("#pw1").val()`

#### The HTML

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pw1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control"
           id="pw1" placeholder="Password"
           required minLength=8>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pw2">Repeat Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control"
           id="pw2" placeholder="Password" aria-describedby="pwHelp"
           required minLength=6
           oninput="validate_pw2(this)">
    <small id="pwHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Please repeat your password</small>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
</form>
```

#### The Script

```
<script> 
function validate_pw2(pw2) {
  if (pw2.value !== $("#pw1").val()) {
    pw2.setCustomValidity("Duplicate passwords do not match");
  } else {
    pw2.setCustomValidity(""); // is valid
  }
}
</script>
```

The important parts are the `oninput` in `#pw2`, which attempts to validate every time the value its changed. Then the `setCustomValidity` call provides the user message displayed when invalid, the empty string is used when it is now valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a check to verify the password values are the same and abort the submission if they're not.

```
 var form = document.getElementById("form-validation");
 form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {          
      if ( document.getElementById("validation2").value != document.getElementById("validation3").value ) {
          alert("Password mismatch");
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
      }
      else if (form.checkValidity() == false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
      }
      form.classList.add("was-validated");
    }, false);
```

You would just change the alert window to show error text to your user.  Here is an example to see how it would look:   https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/55184/

Another suggestion would be to use something like jQuery so that the syntax is less cumbersome to deal with.  But that's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

From your code `checkValidity()` will check only the validity of the form HTML5 constraint (required, format, pattern, min, max), but there is no constraint for verify password. In reality this is like comparing if the content of 2 fields is the same. Also if you want to cancel the form submission, you also needs to `return false;` at the end. Normally HTML5 will not submit a form that has validation errors.

In you case I will suggest make a validation while you are typing on the validation field, and disable the submit button until the passwords match.

```
document.getElementById('validation3').addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
    if(this.value !== document.getElementById('validation2').value){
        document.getElementById('validation4').disabled=true;
        this.classList.replace('pass','nopass');
    }else{
        document.getElementById('validation4').disabled=false;
        this.classList.replace('nopass','pass');
    }
}
```

You will need to assign an `id='validation4'` to the submit button. To make visual changes you could create a CSS rules to handle this ('pass','nopass').